# Wordpress Gutenberg how to allow only specific custom block in custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

i am very new to gutenberg and wordpress development in general and somehow cannot find documentation on this regard.

So i am developing a plugin which also comes with a custom template using this approach:
https://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/

Apart from that my plugin also comes with a custom dynamic block.

Now my question is how can i make my custom template explicitly only allow for
my custom block to be used?

The best scenario would be that the editor only shows my custom block when the template is active or selected, but if this is not possible maybe something like an alert or error when trying to save the page or post with something else than my custom block would also suffice the case.

many thanks in advance!